# how can i change UILabel text in tableView with delay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, uilabel

I use a custom cell in table view I have two label one for the icon ( I use icon from font ) and the second is the title of the cell

I have an array of icon from the font and I want to make them in the label, after every 30 second .

For example, I have an array of icon ( message , facebook , twitter , instagram) . I want in first time the label take the first in Array and after every 30 second take next one.

```
        socialIcon = ["\u{ea61}","\u{e8c7}","\u{e8c8}","\u{e324}"] // partage + facebook + tweeter + message
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "animate", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
timer.fire()



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        /*let cell =  UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Stretch Header"
        cell.selectionStyle = .None*/

  //  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! ParametreViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParametreViewCell

    cell.iconLabel.font = UIFont(name:"innovi", size: 20)

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.paramTable[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        func animate()
        {
        UIView.transitionWithView(cell.iconLabel,
                                  duration: 1.0,
                                  options: [.CurveEaseInOut],
                                  animations: { () -> Void in
                                    if (self.counter < self.socialIcon.count)
                                    {
                                        self.counter += 1
                                        cell.iconLabel.text = self.socialIcon[self.counter]
                                        print (cell.iconLabel.text )
                                    }

            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.iconLabel.text = self.iconTable[indexPath.row]
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Use `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
    });` put animation inside the dispatch block, it will execute after 2 secs.

Comment: The code doesn't make sense to me. Why do you call `timer.fire()` and why is it done in the top level of a class (which isn't valid Swift)?

Comment: you won't be able to do this within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`... try animating it in `willDisplay` method

Comment: @iphonic I made what you told me and doesn't change after 2 second , it's still the first in my array

Comment: @Andreas yes you're correct it's not a valid swift

Comment: @sargeras if i used in will display that not make change after delay 2.0 s , it will be done in the fist tima only . ( i don't now if it'ss corrent ) 

i want when the view display the label change what i was in my table view every 2s not the fist time only . i wan't it to continuously change when the user not change the view . and if he change the view and he will back that make the same animation

Comment: you shouldn't be making it inline method rather approach from here `func animate() {
            for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
                if let customCell = cell as? ParametreViewCell {
                    // follow up changes here
                    
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: @sargeras it's ok and how i can fixed this changes in the first cell only . because now it's change but in every cell and me i have 4 icon and i wan't it change in the first cell only

Comment: `func animate() {
            var indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            if let ifExists = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPath) where ifExists {
                let customCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                // follow up changes here
            }
        }`

Comment: @sargeras thx it's work :D .. i posted the correct code in Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParametreViewCell

    cell.iconLabel.font = UIFont(name:"innovi", size: 20)

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.paramTable[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell.iconLabel.text = self.socialIcon[0]
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(animate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    else
    {
        cell.iconLabel.text = self.iconTable[indexPath.row]
    }


    return cell
}

func animate() {
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    if let ifExists = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPath)
        where ifExists {
        let customCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ParametreViewCell
        UIView.transitionWithView(customCell.iconLabel,
                                  duration: 1.0,
                                  options: [.CurveEaseInOut],
                                  animations: { () -> Void in
                                    if (self.counter < self.socialIcon.count )
                                    {
                                        customCell.iconLabel.text = self.socialIcon[self.counter]
                                        self.counter += 1

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                         self.counter = 0
                                    }
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can avoid `if` altogether... why not use... `customCell.iconLabel.text = self.socialIcon[self.counter]
        self.counter += 1
        self.counter %= self.socialIcon.count
        `